# How can I create a Xen VM using two physical disks (SSD/HDD)?

Tags: virtual-machine, fedora, xen

I am running Xen on Fedora 21 and want to upgrade my Notebook with a SSD. I'd like to run the dom0 and the OS part of the domUs on the SSD but store their data on the HDD. I only want to buy a 128 GB SSD because of pricing but have to store a lot of code and binaries.

Is there a way to assign another image to the domU (saved on the HDD) that the domU will recognize as another disk? Do you have any recommendations how to solve this? What would be the best performing solution? Is this possible with an LVM setup as well?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. I am adding an IDE Device in virt-manager containing the .img file on the HDD. Another way would be adding a LVM partition to the domU. It's really easy to achieve with virt-manager.